# Show a loading view and switching to TabBarController in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, tabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iPhone application that have a TabBarController with two tabs.
Each tab contains a UIWebView that loads a web page from my web site.

I want to add a view that will function as a welcome screen that doesn't show the TabBarController itself (full screen view) and indicates that the application is being loaded.
After that I want to hide the welcome screen and show the TabBarController

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to implement this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a modal view controller for the loading view:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

If you present the modal view controller as soon as your app launches (with no animation), it will be on top of everything, including the tab bar, even if it was presented by one of the tab view controllers.

Once the loading is done, you can dismiss the modal view controller:

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

You could animate the dismissal or not.

If your Default.png (launch screenshot) looks like the modal view, the whole thing should be pretty seamless.